# Proper use of internationalization

Tags: php, translation, localization, wp-kses

Regarding internationalization which of the two would be the proper correct way to process the translation.

```
echo '<p>' . esc_html__( 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing', 'textdomain' ) . '</p>';
```

or

```
printf( '<p>%1$s</p>', esc_html__( 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing', 'textdomain' ) );
```

And if i need to add wrap the following within p tags i would just need to add the p tags as allowed HTML tags. As shown below

```
printf( wp_kses( __( '<p>Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%1$s">Get started here</a>.</p>', 'maker_' ), array( 'a' => array( 'href' => array() ), 'p' => array() ) ), esc_url( admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are exactly the same but I would go for the first one:

- Easier to read
- [No](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d65a038ca38b809cf8f811219f4fe4919ca3c437/wp-admin/plugin-install.php#L97) interpolation, [keep](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f1ba1918c925510822a48fb83c1e74d22d7f0c46/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L217) interpolation for variables

And, including the tags inside the format is making things more complicated, I can think of designers being tempted to use more tags if they see you are using them.